# how to fixed position in IE7 and IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have header1 div in page and I want set *position: fixed* top and center in IE7 and IE6. at multi resolution.

[EX Resolution](http://imageupload.co.uk/viewer.php?file=h8bro3k24f0pn6brjooj.jpg)

[EX Resolution](http://imageupload.co.uk/viewer.php?file=rgsytpgtvzwav42gqa5t.jpg)

I use this code in css:

```
.page
{
width:900px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
}
.header1
{
width: 500px;
height: 60px;
float: right;
position: fixed;
display: block;
z-index: 1100; 
margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="page">
<div class="header1"></div>
</div>
```

OR

```
.page
{
width:900px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
}
.header1
{
width: 500px;
height: 60px;
float: right;
position: fixed;
display: block;
z-index: 1100; 
top: 0px;
    right: 0px; /*right: X px*/
    left: 0px; /*left: X px*/
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="page">
<div class="header1"></div>
</div>
```

it's working in IE 8+,.. but not working in IE7 And 6.

Comment: pity the one(s) who still target ie6 & ie7. Come on man!

Comment: any by the way never add "Please help me." in your questions.

Comment: If I were you, I would simply refuse to work with ie6 and ie7.

Comment: wait till it's a 2 day old question and I will place a bounty on it with thanks to you.

Comment: visitors my site use a IE7 and IE6.

Comment: "visitors my site use a IE7 and IE6" - what site that would be? and if you could provide one, I will offer you free teleport of the site to HTML5 even in "NCSA Mosaic".

Comment: @BabakSaeedi - just because visitors use old browsers doesn't mean your site has to be perfect for them. You could make the site work for them without it being perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE6 does not support `position:fixed`.

IE7 *does* support it, but has bugs.

Ultimately, you will not be able to get this working using pure CSS. You *might* be able to make it work using a javascript polyfill script that adds newer browser features to older IE versions.

The only polyfill script that I know of which includes this feature is [ie7.js / ie8.js /ie9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). This script adds a whole load of extra features to old IE versions, including `position:fixed`. It's not perfect, but it might just do the trick for you.

Hope that helps.

You can find out more about the browser support here: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/

Comment: bada bada bada. +1 in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Add DocType Tag on top of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: i use aspx page (asp.net) and this tag is default

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems but try

```
.page
{
width:900px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
padding:0pt

}
```

This can lead to you putting more CSS for a less effect, IE6 can be problem.

Answer (score 1):

position:fixed should be given to the parent container and not the child one

is this what you are asking for

```
.page
{
 width:100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;   

}
.header1
{
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about IE 6 or IE7, IE 8, 9, & 10 are used more, and thats only a portion of internet users that don't really worry about the internet, the rest of us use Firefox, Opera, and Chrome.